# Small World: Do Orcs Get Race Bonus When Conquering Abandoned Territories?

Tags: small-world

So Orcs get a bonus for conquering unoccupied territories.  If the Orcs abandon a territory and then re-conquer it later in a turn, do they get the bonus? Technically they are conquering an unoccupied territory, but should it read "unoccupied at start of the player's turn?"

Comment: I was under the impression that you couldn't abandon a territory and reconquer it that turn. Is that correct?

Comment: @nicole - you should ask that as your own question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have it backwards.  Orcs do not gain a bonus for conquering unoccupied territories.  From the [Rule Book](http://cdn0.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_rules_en.pdf), emphasis mine:

> **Orcs**
>
> Each **not empty** Region your Orcs conquered this turn is worth 1 bonus Victory coin, at the end of your turn.

Vacating a territory would mean that it was unoccupied when conquered, and therefore the orcs would not get a bonus.

Comment: Thanks for the correction : ) I didn't have the game in front of my when I was asking Small World questions that day. Simple mistake!